# Could the balloon that says something like "You can also check the checkmark button to accept this answer" not effectively disable that button?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, privileges, user-interface

I posted one of my first questions to one site under the SE umbrella, got a good answer, and went to upvote and accept it per the usual common practice.

The upvoting was no problem; I clicked the appropriate circle and it immediately registered my upvote.

However, perhaps because I was new to that specific forum, a balloon popped up explaining to me that I could also click on the "Accept" button... and with its positing, it took me three or four clicks over the "Accept" button area to, after dismissing the balloon, register that I was trying to click the "Accept" button and mark the answer as accepted.

Two requests in relation to this experience:

1. Perhaps with a little bit of JavaScript pixel dust, could the UI be set so that any click over the "Accept" button area registers as effectively clicking the "Accept" button regardless of what balloons are hovering over? (Or could balloons like that be positioned so they don't block the user from clicking the "Accept" button?)
2. Could there be some low threshold of reputation summed across all SE sites that triggers "Congratulations! You appear to be toilet trained." privileges, including not having further explanation of basics like how to accept an answer?
3. The SE umbrella has a lot of social rules, some of which are not obvious to outsiders with good manners. Most of these will be clearly and politely explained to someone who unwittingly breaks them and does not persist in breaking the rules after they have been clearly explained. Besides the balloon I mentioned, veterans will often explain politely how to accept an answer and why you want to do so if there's someone who appears to be new to the system and is asking questions and getting good answers but not accepting. In terms of automatically awarded privileges, though, could privileges that relate to understanding social rules, could "**You understand this social rule.**" privileges be handled on an umbrella-wide rather than site-specific basis?

Comment: I wouldn't tie the hide-acceptance-tip privilege to rep, but rather to having the Scholar badge on at least (1/3/5) sites. Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure there's only one badge-related privilege at present, and it's not a cross-site badge check either.

Comment: Well, if the basic concerns are addressed, whether along lines I outlined by some other of many appropriate approaches, I'd be delighted.

Comment: "Or could balloons like that be positioned so they don't block the user from clicking the "Accept" button?" This. Seriously guys, this is basic UX stuff. Microsoft makes it a point to state this explicitly in all their Windows design documents for a reason.

Comment: Should be on Meta SE as this isn't related to Stack Overflow specifically, and the Stack Exchange sites are *not forums*, please do not refer to them as such.

Comment: Hey there. I have marked this as [meta-tag:status-norepro], since we can no longer reproduce the issue you reported (I don't believe I've seen a fix for it go through, though, so please ping me if you're able to reproduce). Regarding your other requests: please consider making those a separate [meta-tag:feature-request] question (preferably on [meta.se]) — it's difficult to know what's being voted on if your question includes several different requests.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not able to reproduce the issue, the balloon is below the accept answer checkmark.

[image: accept answer prompt]

A screen capture of the issue as you see it might help (maybe you're using a smaller resolution, etc.?).

Comment: I was going to add a comment to my original note saying "I upvoted and accepted an answer in another forum with the balloon present but not interfering with clicking the "Accept" button. I believe that the team responded by making appropriate slight revisions so the balloon does not interfere. **I believe this is a change**, possibly made in response to my question

Comment: This issue isn't reproducible as this issue is not a Stack Overflow issue.